# Dictionary<string, object> how I can take the object value

Tags: c#, .net, keyvaluepair

I have the method

```
HandleNotification(string message, Dictionary<string, object> additionalData, bool isActive)
```

and I would take the from additionalData the value.

I have this additional data:

```
Extracoins:4
```

I don't understand how I can take the value 4 from additionalData for a specific key Extracoins.

Comment: What language are you using? C#?

Comment: Yes I use c# language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a value from a Dictionary like this if your only interested in accessing one specific key.

```
object value = null;
additionalData.TryGetValue("Extracoins", out value);
```

That way object will be the value in the Dictionary or it will remain null if the value is not found.

Or you can do:

```
if (additionalData.ContainsKey("Extracoins"))
{
    object value = additionalData["Extracoins"];
}
```

Finally if you wanted to iterate over all the values in the Dictionary until you get the correct value you could do:

```
object value = null;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in additionalData)
{
    if (pair.Key == "Extracoins")
    {
        value = pair.Value;
    }
}
```